# New user, broken bash prompt parsing?

Tags: bash, bashrc, prompt

I created a new user.  When I `su` into the new user, I get the following bash prompt:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w$
```

For what it's worth, I created this user with the following Ansible task:

```
user:
  name: "{{ project_name }}"
  create_home: yes
```

Edit: `grep PS1 ~/.bashrc` gives

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

Comment: What does `grep PS1 ~/.bashrc` show (when being the new user)?

Comment: That ^^^.  The  \u is user \w is current directory,  \h is hostname. You have a prompt that is not set correctly.

Comment: ... or possibly you have set a bash-appropriate `PS1` but are actually running a different login shell (such as `dash`) that doesn't know how to interpret the escapes

Comment: @PerlDuck and @Rinzwind: I just added the `grep PS1 ~/.bashrc` output.

Comment: @steeldriver -- that's interesting -- I did enter the bash version.  Here's the result: `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
`

Comment: I also find that interesting and maybe @steeldriver is right about the different shell. So: what does `ps $$` show? (I'm asking because I get a similar weird prompt when running `dash` instead of `bash`.)

Comment: @PerlDuck I can get the reported behavior by sourcing the default `~/.bashrc` from a `dash` shell - while it's not hard to believe that `ansible` might be configured to create users with `/bin/sh` as the login shell, it's more curious why it would source one of bash's rc files (if that is in fact what's happening). Unless maybe the OP is setting a bash-specific `PS1` via `~/.profile`?

Comment: @steeldriver Either that way or there's an unconditional `. .bashrc` in `.profile`. I just ran `dash` from within my `bash` and – bang – the prompt was broken.

Comment: I deleted the user, and then recreated it using adduser.  Since the home directory already existed, adduser reported that it would skip the step of copying over the skeleton.

When I su into the refreshed user, the bash prompt now works.  Then, when I type `dash`, it goes back to the broken parsing.

So the ansible dash theory does seem plausible.

Comment: Cool. Note that `/bin/sh` in Ubuntu is actually a symlink to `dash`, so this sounds reasonable.

Comment: Just *running* dash from bash shouldn't break the prompt - unless `PS1` is being exported (which it usually isn't - perhaps for exactly this sort of reason?)

Comment: @steeldriver Ahh, yes. I actually `export PS1` from my `.bashrc` (because I did so for the last X years). You are right, that's superfluous. When I started using Linux I was confused about which variable needs `export` and which doesn't, so I used it all the way down and then simply carried it over to new installations. LOL.

Comment: I found an ansible option for the user command called `shell`.  I then created a (new) new user without that option set, and verified that the prompt was broken.  Finally, I set the option to `/bin/bash` and ran the task again and the prompt for the new new user was restored.  @steeldriver: Running dash still breaks the prompt though.

Comment: I think I'd consider this solved at this point.  @steeldriver (or PerlDuck -- can only notify one person) if either of you want to write it up I can accept the writeup.  If not, I'll write up the fix for the ansible script.  Thanks a ton for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a mixed shell problem.  The prompt constant was set to something that the ansible default shell (dash?) couldn't parse.  To solve it, I just specified bash as the default shell.

```
  user:
    name: "{{ project_name }}"
    create_home: yes
    shell: /bin/bash
```